# Register asterisk to sip trunk

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, gsm

I want to register my asterisk server to a SIP trunk. I have added following piece of code in my sip.conf and extensions.conf

sip.conf

```
[general]
register => myusername:mypassword@sip.flowroute.com
allow=ulaw

[flowroute]                     ; keep this lowercase, do not change format
type=friend
secret=mypassword
username=myusername
host=sip.flowroute.com
dtmfmode=rfc2833
context=inbound            
canreinvite=no
allow=ulaw                   
insecure=port,invite
fromdomain=sip.flowroute.com
```

extensions.conf

```
[outgoing]
exten=> _03.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@flowroute,30)
```

when i do 'sip show peers' in asterisk, it shows

```
CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status      Description 

flowroute/84106639        216.115.69.144                               a             5060     Unmonitored  

goip/goip                 192.168.10.6                             D   a             5060     OK (6 ms)
```

When I visit the my sip provider's management console it doesn't show any registration with asterisk. Please guide in this regard

Thanks

Comment: `sip show peer flowroute` just for completeness.

Answer (score 5):

The config looks fine at first sight. Go on and try to debug your setup:

1. use "sip show registry" inside of asterisk to display the ougoing registrations
2. enable sip debugging: "sip set debug on" (shows the sip traffic within asterisk cli)
3. force a register attempt: "sip reload" and monitor the cli for appearing sip messages

If step 2 only shows outgoing but not incoming packets, you might have a firewall issue.

Comment: sip show registry

Comment: sip show registry shows 0 sip registration and debug logs displays no logs showing any connection established (outgoing/incoming) with sip trunk. Sip messages exchanged with goip are visible but no logs with sip trunk. Do I need to add some more configs in sip trunk ?

Comment: I think i spotted a problem in your sip.conf: please change username= to defaultuser=. See https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/configs/samples/sip.conf.sample for a reference

Answer (score 3):

First, the register line should have a path set at the end, like:

```
register => myusername:mypassword:myusername@sip.flowroute.com/84106639
```

Then do a *sip reload* or *service asterisk restart*. After that, the *sip show peers* command should return some kind of status. The qualify=yes option is useful too to check IP connectivity and SIP service status.

Also, your *[outgoing]* rule in the dialplan should be:

```
exten=> _03.,1,Dial(SIP/flowroute/${EXTEN},30)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing two items to be placed directly under your `register =>` entry.

`[general]`
`register => myusername:mypassword@sip.flowroute.com`
`registertimeout=20`
`registerattempts=0`

As soon as you enter these in sip.conf, at the asterisk console enter:
*CLI>  `sip reload`
*CLI>  `sip show registry`

Answer (score 2):

i) use qualify=yes in sip.conf then sip reload and run command sip show peers and check status is ok or not of your flowroute.

ii) Also stop firewall service and check status.

Comment: 1) sip show registry shows successful registration however sip show peers show unmonitored status. Also the registration timed out error appearing frequently. What does this mean?

Comment: correction: sip show registry shows that registration request has been sent but not getting a response back. What could be the possible cause for this?