# SIP registration timed out

Tags: routing, asterisk, voip, sip, trunk

I am facing trouble in registering asterisk to SIP trunk. When I do >sip show registry, it shows SIP request is send but never gets response back. I cannot even ping sip.flowroute.com. My firewall is disabled and system is not behind NAT. What could be possible cause for this. Following are my configs

sip.conf

```
[general]
register => myusername:mypassword@sip.flowroute.com
allow=ulaw

[flowroute]                     ; keep this lowercase, do not change format
type=peer
secret=mypassword
username=myusername
host=sip.flowroute.com
transport-udp
port=5060
dtmfmode=rfc2833
context=inbound            
canreinvite=no
allow=ulaw                   
insecure=port,invite
fromdomain=sip.flowroute.com
qualify=yes
```

extensions.conf

```
[outgoing]
exten=> _03.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@flowroute,30)
```

Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted the provider, flowroute.com, yet?

You opened another trend recently regarding having trouble authenticating the PEER for flowroute.com, [prior question show here](https://serverfault.com/questions/840444/register-asterisk-to-sip-trunk). There is a chance that the provider saw your earlier failed attempts as an invalid attempt to connect and has since blocked your public IP. This could result in the peer failing to authenticate and unable to ping their service. Their support should be able to confirm if your IP is blocked, and possibly "white-list" your IP to allow connection.

First thing I would do is:

1. Confirm you can resolve the ip address correctly, their support should be able to confirm this IP address is correct.
2. Confirm you can ping IP address, you said you could not.
3. Run a trace route to the IP address, this will help their support to start identifying where the connection is failing. If they are blocking you you should see it fail when it reaches their network edge.

FWIW this is what I saw when I did these steps

```
nslookup sip.flowroute.com  Address 1: 216.115.69.144

Pinging 216.115.69.144 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.115.69.144: bytes=32 time=72ms TTL=45

Tracing route to 216.115.69.144 over a maximum of 30 hops
!
Removed my LAN hops and my ISP hops
!
  7    65 ms    65 ms    78 ms  ae-0-11.bar1.LasVegas1.Level3.net [4.69.148.125]
  8    69 ms    67 ms    68 ms  SWITCH-COMM.bar1.LasVegas1.Level3.net [4.35.35.42]
  9    73 ms    75 ms    75 ms  be76.las-core7-1.switchnap.com [66.209.64.105]
 10    72 ms    72 ms    72 ms  be771.las-agg7s3-1.supernap.com [66.209.72.14]
 11    72 ms    72 ms    72 ms  flowroute.demarc1.switchnap.com [216.115.64.190]
 12    73 ms    73 ms    73 ms  216.115.69.189
 13    72 ms    72 ms    72 ms  216.115.69.144

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Just in case I added port forwarding to my router but no success. Ping is not getting response back and '*.*.*.*' in traceroute.

Comment: Now I can ping sip.flowroute.com (216.115.69.144) and traceroute it. Once 'sip show registry' showed up the trunk as registered however it didn't show up on web console as active registration. But next time we restarted asterisk the registration kept on timing out. Current status is that it's not working but we can ping and traceroute successfully.

Comment: It is solved. Registration was unsuccessful because my system was part of two networks. There were two default routes present, which was creating confusion for outgoing packets. Thanks everyone for support